# Display a div inside a table through JS and position absolute moves the table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am playing around with jQuery in order to have a confirm box when I click on a delete link in a table.
I managed to make it work, but when the box is displayed, the columns are moving to the left which is not perfect.

I don't know where it comes from: my CSS, my JS, Foundation CSS?...
I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLjebd76/1/) so you can check the result. It happens when you click on Delete.

Here's the code in the JSFiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Confirm delete
    $('.delete-action').click(function() {
        //Get the path of the href
        var item_link = this.href;

        //Select the <tr> and get the width and height
        var item_section = $(this).closest('tr');
        var item_section_width = item_section.outerWidth();
        var item_section_height = item_section.outerHeight();

        //Add css to the <tr>
        item_section.css('position', 'relative');

        //Display the confirm box in the <tr>
        item_section.append('<div class="delete-box" style="position:absolute;width:'+item_section_width+'px;height:'+item_section_height+'px;top:0;left:0" >\n\
            <div>Are you sure you want to delete this entry? <a href="'+item_link+'" class="delete-yes">Oui</a><a class="delete-no">Non</a></div>\n\
        </div>');

        //Proceed with delete
        $('.delete-yes').click(function() {
            return true;
        });

        //Do not delete, remove the box
        $('.delete-no').click(function() {
            $('.delete-box').fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.delete-box {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.delete-box div {
  margin: auto;
}

.delete-box div a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.delete-box div .delete-yes {
  background-color: green;
}

.delete-box div .delete-yes:hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.delete-box div .delete-no {
  background-color: red;
}

.delete-box div .delete-no:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation-float.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <title>Confirm box for a delete row in a Table - jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <h1>Confirm box in a Table</h1>
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Last update</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>This is a title</td>
      <td>2017-07-08</td>
      <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</i></a> - <a href="" class="delete-action"><i class="fa fa-close"> Delete</i></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>This is a title</td>
      <td>2017-07-08</td>
      <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</i></a> - <a href="" class="delete-action"><i class="fa fa-close"> Delete</i></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>This is a title</td>
      <td>2017-07-08</td>
      <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</i></a> - <a href="" class="delete-action"><i class="fa fa-close"> Delete</i></a></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea where it can come from?

Comment: I cannot see column moving. Works good for me.

Comment: it works... i also found good.

Comment: @AKA, seems to be happening in Firefox. And seems to be due to how each browse is handling the adding of a DIV to a TR (which isn't valid html).

Comment: Well actually, checking on chrome, what I did does not even work... I was doing it on FF indeed.

Comment: Your TR's need a `position:relative` style so that the delete container's absolute position acts off that instead of some further up parent's. Or use valid html and append the delete container in a valid place and calculate the actual position to put it over the TR.

Comment: The <tr> has a position:relative, I set it in the JavaScript. I will search for a better and valid way to do it.

Comment: If you try proper markup, I got it working in Firefox by wrapping your div in `<td style="margin:0; width: 0; padding: 0;">`,`</td>`. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/LLjebd76/2/

Comment: I tried another way without a div : https://jsfiddle.net/LLjebd76/3/ This works in FF and chrome and I don't reproduce the bug!

Answer (score 0):

I finally changed the way to do it, switching from a 'div' solution to a 'td' solution. Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/LLjebd76/3/

```js
// Foundation
$(document).foundation();

// jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Confirm delete
    $('.delete-action').click(function() {
        //Get the path of the href
        var item_link = $(this).attr('href');

        //Select the <tr> and get the height
        var item_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var item_tr_height = item_tr.outerHeight();
        var item_tr_value = item_tr.html();

        //Display the confirm box in the <tr>
        item_tr.empty();
        item_tr.append('<td colspan="3" height="'+item_tr_height+'" class="delete-box">\
         Are you sure you want to delete this entry? <a href="'+item_link+'" class="delete-yes">Yes</a><a class="delete-no">No</a>\
        </td>');

        //Proceed with delete
        $('.delete-yes').click(function() {
            return true;
        });

        //Do not delete, remove the box
        $('.delete-no').click(function() {
            item_tr.empty().append(item_tr_value);

            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.delete-box {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.delete-box a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.delete-box .delete-yes {
  background-color: green;
}

.delete-box .delete-yes:hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.delete-box .delete-no {
  background-color: red;
}

.delete-box .delete-no:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation-float.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

 <title>Confirm box for a delete row in a Table - jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <h1>Confirm box in a Table</h1>
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Last update</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>This is a title 1</td>
      <td>2017-07-08</td>
      <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</i></a> - <a href="" class="delete-action"><i class="fa fa-close"> Delete</i></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>This is a title 2</td>
      <td>2017-07-09</td>
      <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</i></a> - <a href="" class="delete-action"><i class="fa fa-close"> Delete</i></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>This is a title 3</td>
      <td>2017-07-10</td>
      <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</i></a> - <a href="" class="delete-action"><i class="fa fa-close"> Delete</i></a></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```